# Electric portable lamps in 1917 - how realistic is this depiction?

Tags: realism, props, 1917

I've just seen "1917" and when Schofield and Blake were in enemy trenches - the rat tripwire scene - they were using some portable lamps.

My question is - how realistic is this depiction and if it is realistic - what were technical specs of these lamps? They are supposedly electric but I’d be very surprised if they last longer than half an hour.

[image: seconds before a disaster]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that is called a [Beacon Army Light](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/beacon-army-light-pat-nov-13-1917-ww-135481368) and just from cursory google searches on the topic the movies seems to be authentic to the time in terms of flash light technology.

Also [found this one](https://www.worthpoint.com/worthopedia/beacon-army-light-1917-patent-237110673) that looks like it says they last around 5 hours pretty neat!